# pass json list as header parameter of Dio Post method in Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, post, dio

I want to send the list of cart items like this in the header parameter of Dio post method in FLutter/Dart.

```
https://www.example.com?cart=[{"product_id": "8", "category_id": "19", "shop_id": "11", "shop_name": "shopName", "quantity": "2", "descriptions": "test"}]
```

but the dio converts each fields into something like `cart[0][product_id]=8`

```
https://www.example.com?cart[0][product_id]=8&cart[0][category_id]=19&cart[0][shop_id]=11&cart[0][shop_name]=shopName&cart[0][quantity]=2&cart[0][descriptions]=test
```

Comment: It's not clear if you want the data structure as a URL parameter, as a header, or as the body of the post.  Until you're clear, Dio can only do what you tell it. :)

Comment: my backend team wants me to pass the json list as parameter in a post header(like first example URL) , but when i try to pass json list in header as parameter it changes into URL like in second example.